# Как отключить подгрузку символов в Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

При каждой компиляции проекта библиотеки символов подгружаются

Comment: собирать release- вместо debug-версии? :)

Comment: @isnullxbh Прошу прощения, я ещё плоховато знаю студию. Не могли бы Вы поподробнее рассказать?

Comment: @isnullxbh Хорошо, я сменил на releas, но оно так же подгружает XD

Comment: На самом деле я только предположил - посмотрите эту [ссылку](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-set-debug-and-release-configurations?view=vs-2017), там, правда, в контексте C#, но это не критично :)

Comment: Тогда смотрите это: https://stackoverflow.com/a/869182/6266408

Comment: @isnullxbh Благодарю, Помогло!

Comment: @isnullxbh оформите ответом.